# Recover and Roll back SQL DB State

Tags: sql-server, database, rollback, recovery

Friends,

I'm looking for an solution on SQL DB server. I'm being working in support organization on managing SQL Server.

When we make some changes on SQL DB (Schema changes, table alteration, data etc..) and found it is not compatible we need to roll back easily.

Something like, before i make any changes on my DB server need to preserve current state of DB and once changes were made and if looks good then i can commit permanantly. If not working properly i can discard the changes and revert to previous state quickly.

Is there any such option available?

Comment: can't it be done using trigger?

Comment: create a database snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Database Snapshot which helps to prevent administrative error.

Here is a link that can help you understand how to create and apply database snapshot:

[Database Snapshot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx)

Comment: I will try on this. Meanwhile did anyone setup this already?  If yes, does it affect with DB Size?